# Workaround for `count.index` in Terraform Module

Tags: module, count, terraform

I need a workaround for using `count.index` inside a module block for some input variables. I have a habit of over-complicating problems, so maybe there's a much easier solution.

**File/Folder Structure:**

```
modules/
  main.tf
  ignition/
    main.tf
    modules/
      files/
        main.tf
      template_files/
        main.tf
```

**End Goal:** Create an Ignition file for each instance I'm deploying. Each Ignition file has instance-specific info like hostname, IP address, etc.

All of this code works if I use a static value or a variable without `cound.index`.  I need help coming up with a workaround for the `address`, `gateway`, and `hostname` variables specifically.  If I need to process the `count.index` inside one of the child modules, that's totally fine.  I can't seem to wrap my brain around that though.  I've tried `null_data_source` and `null_resource` blocks from the child modules to achieve that, but so far no luck.

Variables:

```
workers = {
  Lab1 = {
    "lab1k8sc8r001" = "192.168.17.100/24"
  }
  Lab2 = {
    "lab2k8sc8r001" = "192.168.18.100/24"
  }
}

gateway = {
  Lab1 = [
    "192.168.17.1",
  ]
  Lab2 = [
    "192.168.18.1",
  ]
}
```

From `modules/main.tf`, I'm calling the `ignition` module:

```
module "ignition_workers" {
  source = "./modules/ignition"

  virtual_machines     = var.workers[terraform.workspace]
  ssh_public_keys      = var.ssh_public_keys

  files = [
    "files_90-disable-auto-updates.yaml",
    "files_90-disable-console-logs.yaml",
  ]

  template_files = {
    "files_eth0.nmconnection.yaml" = {
      interface-name = "eth0",
      address = element(values(var.workers[terraform.workspace]), count.index),
      gateway = element(var.gateway, count.index % length(var.gateway)),
      dns = join(";", var.dns_servers),
      dns-search = var.domain,
    }
    "files_etc_hostname.yaml"  = {
      hostname = element(keys(var.workers[terraform.workspace]), count.index),
    }
    "files_chronyd.yaml" = {
      ntp_server = var.ntp_server,
    }
  }
}
```

From `modules/ignition/main.tf` I take the `files` and `template_files` variables to build the Ignition config:

```
module "ingition_file_snippets" {
  source = "./modules/files"
  files  = var.files
}

module "ingition_template_file_snippets" {
  source          = "./modules/template_files"
  template_files  = var.template_files
}

data "ct_config" "fedora-coreos-config" {
  count = length(var.virtual_machines)

  content = templatefile("${path.module}/assets/files_ssh_authorized_keys.yaml", {
    ssh_public_keys = var.ssh_public_keys
    })
  pretty_print = true
  snippets = setunion(values(module.ingition_file_snippets.files), values(module.ingition_template_file_snippets.files))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve so I can not give any detailed examples.

But `modules` in terraform do not support `count` or `for_each` yet. So you can also not use `count.index`.

You might want to change your module to take lists/maps of input and create those lists/maps via [for-expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) by transforming them from some input variables.
You can combine `for` with `if` to create a filtered subset of your source list/map. Like in:

```
[for s in var.list : upper(s) if s != ""]
```

I hope this helps you work around the missing `count` support.

Comment: The issue comes from the input variable to the module.  Overall, it's a map of filenames and the values I'm replacing later with the templatefile() function.
The values can be a map, or list, or string.  I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to deal with those different situations.

Comment: **Example:** (Sorry for the text wrapping...)

`variable "template_files" {
  type = any
  default = {
    "eth0.nmconnection.yaml" = {
      interface-name = "eth0",
      addresses = {
        "lab1k8sc8r001" = "192.168.17.100/24"
      },
      gateway = [
        "192.168.17.1",
        "192.168.17.1",
      ],
      dns = [
        "192.168.17.2",
      ]
      dns-search = "domain.lcl",
    }
  }
}

output "files" {
  value = tomap({
    for fn, vars in var.template_files : fn => templatefile("${path.module}/assets/${fn}", vars)
  })
}`